# Is tipping in a hotel with the intent of zakat acceptable?

Tags: zakat

Is tipping with the intent that it is zakat acceptable in Islam. For example tipping a waiter in a restaurant or in a hotel or a taxi driver.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first.

Zakat is highly preferred to be given to Muslims, than to the non Muslims.

Next, talking about the poor, first priority is to be given to the **poor who do not ask**, and **then to the poor who ask**.

And finally make sure you abide by this verse...

> And give to the kindred his due and to the Miskin (poor) and to the wayfarer. **But spend not wastefully (your wealth) in the manner of a spendthrift** . (Qur'an 17:26)

So, you would like to consider all the above factors, before you think of tipping.

**Support:** [Who is zakat given to?](http://hidayaresearch.com/who-is-zakat-given-to/)

May the creator guide us all.